# UnityEngine.SceneManagement assembly reference gone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So, I am going to start of with saying there is no errors with my code what so ever since it worked previously, and it is not changed in any way. My problem lies in the fact that I moved my scripts into folders in an effort to try to organize them a bit. This absolutely borked some of the references to unities library. Specifically the "UnityEngine.SceneManagement" one. I then looked in Visual Studios to find that in the reference section of visual studio [(Depicted in this image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnJqb.png), I could not even find that as a reference, although all other UnityEngine references were there. I do not know how to get it back.

Edit: It also says "No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name."

Comment: Did you move the scripts using Unity's interface? Or did you move them using a file explorer?

Comment: I moved them inside of unity

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is orbetter **was** a custom JavaScript flavour-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Comment: I read that you solved the problem. I also sometimes lose Unity script references, especially when I upgrade the Unity version. Re-importing the project (Assets, Reimport All) always solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Really weird solution, I deleted a script I made, and I don't know why, but unity decided to reload the reference assembly, which also fixed the issue. Do not know how, but it is fixed now.

Comment: Hi Farrow, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)